# Loopback - Best practice to update database field for every api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, middleware

What is the best practice to update a database field for every api call.

I am using loopback & mongodb

1) I have implemented pre processing directive which is triggering for every call. But the problem is how can I access the db object there?

**Middleware json**:

```
{
  "initial:before": {
    "loopback#favicon": {}
  },
  "initial": {
    "./middleware/tracker": {},
  }
 ....
  ...
}
```

**middleware/tracker.js**:

```
module.exports = function(tracker) {
  return function tracker(req, res, next) {
    console.log('Request tracking middleware triggered on %s', req.url);
    // Here I want to update database
    next();
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the models like this:

```
const app = require('../server/server');
app.models.SomeModel.sometMethod(params);
```